# Magento 2 : Custom order email template customization

Tags: magento2, email-templates

I want to customize the email template

I have added as per below by override two files **`default.phmtl and items.phtml`**
(I have added three addition td tags).

Below is email which I receive exactly

[image]

But the order total section is shows problematic.

can any one guide how to move this section right using CSS or any other way

Comment: you can check my answer i have same trouble but something debug and after working it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this by ovrerride **sales_email_order_items.xml** file

Override this file in your theme and add below code

```
<referenceBlock name="order_totals">
     <arguments>
          <argument name="label_properties" xsi:type="string">colspan="5"</argument>
     </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

You just need to change colspan value as per your customization.